# Prevent Spring Boot from caching files

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

During development phase, Spring boot cached the static JS and CSS files, and the changes in them were not reflected even after server restart. Initially I thought Chrome was caching the files but the problem persisted even after i changed browsers, which led me to the conclusion that it was my application which was sending the cached pages.

To disable the cache, I tried to add this key-value pair to the application.properties file as suggested on some SO answers:

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

But even this didn't solve my caching problem. I haven't used any caching related annotations either. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am currently running the project by renaming the file every time I make some changes which is a really long and tiresome process.

The POM dependencies are: `spring-boot-starter-web` which was default when i created project using [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/), and `tomcat-embed-jasper` for compiling JSP. The plugin used is: `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

Comment: Can you please share the complete pom file?

Comment: @NirajJha I couldn't upload entire POM because of company policy, but I have added the details in short

Comment: Basically you want to achieve cache busting, probably these settings will help you.

Comment: spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.enabled=true
spring.resources.chain.strategy.content.paths=/**
spring.resources.chain.strategy.fixed.enabled=true

Comment: @NirajJha This gave `**BeanCreationException:** Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource`

Comment: Remove all those configurations posted by me and see the response header and check Cache-Control: max age, basically we have to set this very minimum or 0.

Comment: @NirajJha But isn't this header used to tell the browser not to cache? The browser isn't the one caching the pages. It's just that my Application is returning cached pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Spring boot dev tools](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3), it provides many features including the **LiveReload** which enables you to hot swap the changes. once dev tools are enabled any changes to static files as well as some changes to java source can be applied without restarting the web server.

Comment: Thanks for the handy tools suggestion. I'll use this for future projects as well. But still, I would really like to know how to disable caching normally using some property/code changes.

Comment: it is not caching, problem is once you start the server, your application is made into a war and its deployed on the web server, now if you make any changes to any files, then they can not be seen by the server, for server to see the new changes you will have to save the changes and restart your server with newly built war.

Comment: That's what I am doing. I am recreating the war and running it on server, still I am getting the previous version results.

Comment: unzip your war and check if your changes are there, if you are creating war correctly and redeploying on the server, then this is not an issue related with server side

Comment: I checked after unzipping the war, and it didn't have the changes. I tried running the Java Application using Eclipse IDE and the result is same.

Comment: then there is some problem in your deployment, are you using vanila eclipse or spring tool suite? for spring boot development spring tool suite is modified eclipse with pre install plugins.

Comment: Vanilla Eclipse Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

`spring.cache` properties are used to control the general-purpose `@Cacheable` mechanism using a provider such Caffeine. You're looking for the configuration for [the Web-specific caching system](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#web-properties), `spring.resources.chain`:

```
spring.resources.chain.cache: false
```

Comment: @PiNaKa30 Then set `logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG` to get a detailed report of how Spring is handling your request.

Comment: Its showing `GET "/css/upload.css", parameters={}` and `Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler ["classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/", "/"]`, which seems to be correct and the code is also 200 OK